# slowcheetah to transform value of an element in config file

Tags: c#, xpath, configuration, configurationmanager, slowcheetah

I know how to change the value of attributes with SlowCheetah, but how would I change the value of the element.

app.Debug.config:

```
 <applicationSettings>
  <MyProgram.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="aName" serializeAs="String">
      <value>myName</value>
    </setting>
  </MyProgram.Properties.Settings>
 </applicationSettings>
```

This was my failed attempt in app.Staging.config:

```
 <applicationSetting>
   <MyProgram.Properties.Settings>
     <setting name="aName" serializeAs="String">
        <value xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(value)">newName</value>
     </setting>
   </MyProgram.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSetting>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<applicationSetting>    
  <MyProgram.Properties.Settings>      
    <setting name="aName" serializeAs="String" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">         
      <value xdt:Transform="Replace">newName</value>     
    </setting>    
  </MyProgram.Properties.Settings> 
</applicationSetting>
```

This should do it!

Comment: what about the user settings?